# I have two bosses to work with. How to work when both say conflicting things?

Tags: management, work-environment

I report directly to the owner of a company, say A, but for directions and help I have to consult a senior, say B. B also reports to A. 
Now A has assigned me some work and wants me to outline the entire work. B at the same time wants me to deliver a specific part of the work first, which can be done separately without going through the other elements.
I am now at crossroads so as how to satisfy both my superiors at the same time.

Answer (score 7):

You throw the conflict back to them to resolve. Write an email addresed to both descibing what each has asked you to do and ask them to set the priorities on the tasks.

Answer (score 5):

It is best to surface this conflict immediately. So A tells you to do something, and a few hours or days later, B gives you different instructions. You need to make sure right then and there that B knows you were given different instructions.

Do not say this:

> But A told me to outline it first!

It implies that B is wrong, and that you won't be following B's instructions. It sets up an argument.

Instead, ask questions:

> Is A ok with waiting for the outline until this part is finished?
>
> I only need another two hours to finish the outline; is this part really too urgent to wait that long?
>
> Has something changed since A told me to outline it all first?

Notice you're not disagreeing. You're not refusing. You're not sending one superior off to work something out with another. You may get answers like "yes, A is fine with it, we discussed it a little while ago" or "none of your business, I've told you what to do" but either way you learn something. You may get "yes, something has changed, 4 days has gone by and A expected the outline the next day. There is no longer time to wait for this subtask. Get it done and then go back to the outline." That's a bit of a reprimand, but at least you understand that the conflict isn't a conflict, it's a change in priorities based on events that have happened since you got your instructions.

Any number of possible explanations may exist for this apparent conflict. Clients call with emergencies, people have to be pulled off things, people change their minds, you misinterpreted what you were told and B has come to clarify, etc etc etc. By asking questions instead of arguing, you can learn what's going on around you and get better at your job.

If all this happened a little while ago, what have you been doing since then? Does B think you're doing what he asked? Does A? If you have been paralyzed since you got this instruction, get the clarity you need in order to move forward, and get it now.

Answer (score 0):

How long will this outline take?  Can you write the outline, showing that the specific part that B wants done will be done first, and then give the outline to A to approve?  Then, if he has a problem with the order of the tasks being done, you can bring up that B wanted you to do it first and let him decide what your priorities should be.

It doesn't sound as if there is a conflict here.  A wants an outline, B wants a task order.  If the outline is going to take so long that you feel B will become impatient waiting for the task to be done, mention to him that you won't be able to get to it until you finish the outline for A.